# How to assert the validate error in sequelizejs unit test with jest?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, jestjs

I am unit testing a User model. The user name shouldn't be empty. The unit test is the following:

```
it('should reject no name', async () => {
   name = '';
   expect(await User.create(payload())).toThrow();
});
```

when `payload` has all the data except with empty name, the unit test throw the following error:

```
 SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Invalid validator function: unique,
    Validation error: Invalid validator function: msg,
    Validation error: column "cell" does not exist
```

However the assertion here `.toThrow` is not right and the test case still fails.  Tried toBeUndefined with no avail. What is the correct assertion for this type of error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `User.create` returns a `Promise` that rejects with the thrown error:

```
await expect(User.create(payload())).rejects.toThrow();  // SUCCESS
```

---

Note that `toThrow` was fixed for promises with [PR 4884](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4884) so if you are using an older version of `Jest` (before 22.0.0) you will need to use something like `toEqual`:

```
await expect(User.create(payload())).rejects.toEqual(expect.any(Error));  // SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this.

```
await expect( User.create(payload())).to.be.rejectedWith(Error)
```

Now, test will pass if user.create throws error, & fail if it didn't throw the error.

Comment: can you tell me, what is User in this code, I mean is it your custom class or its a model? and is it returning promise? And also show me the creation of expect object so I may answer it more precisely.